# Tag-It Autocomplete doesn't trigger list on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete, tag-it

I have this Tag-it plugin up and running with just a flaw that I must correct.

It doesnt't show the list of tags when the mouse enters the input field, even with the `showAutocompleteOnFocus:true,` property.

So far I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#categories").tagit({
                fieldName: "categories[]",
                availableTags: <?php echo $categories; ?>,
                showAutocompleteOnFocus:true,
                allowSpaces:true

            });
        });
</script>

<ul id="categories"><ul>
```

The Categories echo renders like this

```
["Categoria","Categoria 2","Categoria 3","Promoção"]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as my knowledge of JQuery syntax goes, the value of 'fieldName' seems weird, with the square brackets. Have you tried just using "categories" as value?

Also, your PHP variable $categories, what does it look like, when rendered? Could you perhaps include an example of how that piece of code is rendered?

Comment: The filedName is the name of the input field, being that a group, so I can work with several categories when submitting the form later on. I've edited with the categories json array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue on the plugin page on github, and the author solved it

For anyone with the same issue [here's](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/issues/123) the issue page